# Matrix being cut off when read in

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am reading in a cosdist matrix csv file.
This is what it looks like:

```
1.0, 0.695, 0.495, 0.697, 0.669, 0.684
0.695, 1.0, 0.826, 0.42, 0.454, 0.788
0.495, 0.826, 1.0, 0.528, 0.321, 0.517
0.697, 0.42, 0.528, 1.0, 0.224, 0.536
0.669, 0.454, 0.321, 0.224, 1.0, 0.409
0.684, 0.788, 0.517, 0.536, 0.409, 1.0
```

This is my code snippet here:

```
var = pd.read_csv('cosdist.csv', sep=",")
print(var) #test-output

Y20 = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(var)
print(Y20) #test-output

A = pd.DataFrame(scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(Y20))
print(A) #test-output
```

I noticed that when running my full project I am getting a 5x5 matrix instead of the 6x6 matrix as needed. If I add one more row at the top of the csv then I am given the correct matrix. I believe either the pdist or squareform functions cause this issue. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

The matrix if I don't add the top row:

[matrix I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97SI1.png)

The matrix if I add the top row:

[matrix I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGM4l.png)

Comment: You need to add the `header=None` parameter to `pd.read_csv()`. Otherwise, the first row will be interpreted as column headings.

Comment: I suspect that you just need to change the first command to `var = pd.read_csv('cosdist.csv', sep=",", header = None)`

Comment: Review `reax_csv` looking for parameters dealing with names and column headers.. Also what are you displaying, `var` or `Y20`